# Elasticsearch cluster with docker compose in Windows

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am using *Docker 17.04.0-ce* and *Compose 1.12.0* in *Windows*.

I want to create a cluster of 3 *Elasticsearch* nodes (all on the same IP but on different ports). I use the image: *docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0*

When I compose the following yml and check the status in *Cerebro*, I see that no cluster is actually formed (each node does not see the others). 
Any ideas what the problem could be?

```
version: '2'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0
    container_name: es_1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - cluster.name=cp-es-cluster
      - node.name=cloud1
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin="*"
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - discovery.type=zen
      - network.publish_host=192.168.99.100
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:-AssumeMP"
    networks:
      - docker_elk

  elasticsearch_2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0
    container_name: es_2
    ports:
      - "9201:9200"
      - "9301:9300"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=cp-es-cluster
      - node.name=cloud2
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin="*"
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - discovery.type=zen
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=192.168.99.100:9200"
      - network.publish_host=192.168.99.100
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:-AssumeMP"
    networks:
      - docker_elk

  elasticsearch_3:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0
    container_name: es_3
    ports:
      - "9202:9200"
      - "9302:9300"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=cp-es-cluster
      - node.name=cloud3
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin="*"
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - discovery.type=zen
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=192.168.99.100:9200"
      - network.publish_host=192.168.99.100
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:-AssumeMP"
    networks:
      - docker_elk

  cerebro:
    image: yannart/cerebro:0.6.5
    container_name: cerebro
    networks:
      - docker_elk
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  docker_elk:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: What is in your elasticsearch and cerebro folders?

Comment: Dockerfile + sh scripts for ES / conf for Cerbero. The respective dockerfiles use the proper images and simply copy these files inside the images.

Comment: That's cool, but do you realize that it is really hard to troubleshoot your problem without access to these files, right?

Comment: Fair enough. I retried the scenario by using images directly instead of custom build and got the same result. I updated the yml in the problem description, so you can check this. No other files are involved now.

Comment: Nice, thanks. This gets us somewhere - I don't know exactly why yet, but es_1 is exiting after it finishes starting up - and since he's the master, it prevents the other nodes from being discovered.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an answer yet but I've managed to set up a working cluster using elastic's documentation example, here's a link to the gist -https://gist.github.com/yaron-idan/48e2b3d2c66bc1c4f4279b522b2b5f64.
You can use this example to tweak your configuration until it works.

Comment: I tried your code and it works just fine, so I will experiment a bit with my configuration following your example. Thank you for your help!